# Should I ignore schema.rb because extension differs on development/production OS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rails-postgresql, pg

My database uses PostgreSQL. I develop on Mac and this line is needed:

```
  # db/schema.rb on Mac environment
  enable_extension "plpgsql"
```

However, the extension is not required on Linux.

In this case, should we just ignore schema.rb and generate that through db:migrate for both dev and production environments?

Comment: It doesn't seem to hurt production.

Comment: However, Git complains whenever pulling when I forget to `git checkout db/schema.rb`

Comment: No I pull from development, which has `enable_extension`. In production, I do the following: `pull`, `migrate`, `git checkout schema.rb` before I am able to `pull` the next time.

Comment: It doesn't seem right to `git checkout schema.rb` every time, that's why it feels I should just ignore `schema.rb` :(

Comment: I don't believe db/schema.rb is read in either the production or development environments.  It's basically a way for the test environment to dump the schema and re-setup when it runs it's tests. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884429/rails-what-does-schema-rb-do

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood it, the problem is that the auto-generated schema.rb will differ on production and development, and therefore cause changed files in git, because of this extra line.

Is the line generated by the postgres adapter on mac ? If it's been added manually, I'd try to put it somewhere else, maybe in an initializer (where you could switch its use based on the platform via something from here: [Detecting Operating Systems in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784109/detecting-operating-systems-in-ruby) ).

Comment: The changes generated on production should not be in version control.

Nevertheless, if you use different databases in development, a change in that config will cause a different `scheme.rb`, and mess with your versioning. In this case, I'll ignore the `scheme.rb` if it is going to be a derivative file and not manually edited.

Answer (score 0):

I would always use the migrations. `schema.rb` has the downside of being only ruby. If - for some reason - you have plain SQL in your migrations, maybe to use `BIGSERIAL` instead of `SERIAL` or so, you will get a problem with `schema.rb`. Switching to a SQL-based schema-dump only solves part of the problem, leaving possible needed data-corrections or data-seed out of the picture.