# How ActiveRecord finds the attributes of a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

here is my question.

I want to know how `active record` access the tables and columns in a database ?

Comment: can you explain your question in a better way ? like what exactly you want to know.

Comment: i want to know how model finds the table columns

Comment: http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html see if this helps you understand

Answer (score 3):

The majority of the code that answers you question is contained in the [`model_schema.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.2/activerecord/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb) file.

The [`table_name`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.2/activerecord/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb#L102-L105) is the name of the database table corresponding to your model. As explained in the documentation, it is guessed from the model name unless explicitly set.

> Guesses the table name (in forced lower-case) based on the name of the class in the
>   inheritance hierarchy descending directly from ActiveRecord::Base. So if the hierarchy
>   looks like: `Reply < Message < ActiveRecord::Base`, then Message is used
>   to guess the table name even when called on Reply. The rules used to do the guess
>   are handled by the Inflector class in Active Support, which knows almost all common
>   English inflections. You can add new inflections in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`.
>
> Nested classes are given table names prefixed by the singular form of
>   the parent's table name. Enclosing modules are not considered.
>   You can also set your own table name explicitly:
>
> ```
> class Mouse < ActiveRecord::Base
>   self.table_name = "mice"
> end
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can override the table_name method to define your
>   own computation. (Possibly using super to manipulate the default
>   table name.) Example:
>
> ```
> class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
>   def self.table_name
>     "special_" + super
>   end
> end
> ```

For the columns, it's a little bit more complicated. You can start from the [`columns`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.2/activerecord/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb#L207-L213) method that fetches the column definition from the `schema.rb` file and returns them.

Columns are explicitly defined in the `schema.rb` file inside your application.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer to a terrible question

Comment: it doesn't pull from the schema.rb file, though (i have projects with custom db columns that just dump sql). Normally it uses introspection of table via DB calls (for example see activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb and   def column_definitions for how postgresql does it.

Comment: As far as I know, introspection is used only to generate the schema.rb (usually on migration). Once generated, the `schema.rb` is used. In fact, `schema.rb` is required to run the app. If it would use introspection only, the `schema.rb` would not be required.

Comment: I do not have a schema.rb (have structure.sql, as the schema dumper don't like custom fields, that it doesn't now how to deal with), and my apps all work fine :)  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884429/rails-what-does-schema-rb-do

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I'll dig into the code as soon as I have some spare time.

Answer (score 0):

It is done by ORM layer and it follows the rails convention to map the table and there field until you manually configure your model for mapping a table in database

take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

Comment: hi.. can u tell me where exactly the code has written for this?

Comment: @poojaagarwal [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb#L213), I think.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord provides a Base class, which, when subclassed, sets up a mapping between the said class and an existing DB table.

Each finder method allows you to pass arguments into it to perform certain queries on your database without writing raw SQL.

If you're looking for more on the inner workings, here's a good place to start:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb

Answer (score 0):

Take mysql as an example, it has a db call information_schema, and there are table name tables, columns and so on. Mysql use these tables to store the info of each table and its column definition inside other mysql's databases.

Other db provicer may have something similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

It uses  introspection.   If you watch your debug logs, the first time you access the model you should see a query that is probing for the table definition, columns, etc.   I am most familiar with postgres so I'll link to that, but all `connection adapters` do this is a DB specific way.

take a look at  `activerecord / lib / active_record / connection_adapters`   for your database  and along with the `column_definitions` function, which generates the runtime introspection  for postgres this looks like this.

(from https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/60fa355790bd6888ab8758bd4989431256d8ba8e/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb)

```
def column_definitions(table_name) #:nodoc:
          exec_query(<<-end_sql, 'SCHEMA').rows
              SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '#{quote_table_name(table_name)}'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
          end_sql
        end
```

This information is then cached and used to generate the dynamic methods.

Reading the rails source, while it can very confusing is good fun,  and you can see how some of the `magic` works.