# Remove table from schema without deleting it from the database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

I recently starting using an existing database with my Rails project but I realized that all of the tables from that database were merged over.

I still need some of these tables, just not for this project.

I'm afraid deleting them with a migration will delete them from my actual database as well.  Can I just delete them manually from schema.rb?

Comment: By `schema`, do you mean `db/schema.rb`?

Comment: Look here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884429/rails-what-does-schema-rb-do) to read about the purpose of schema.rb, it isn't used by ActiveRecord to load in the DB tables. So deleting anything from there has no purpose.

Comment: Why do you want to remove them from your schema?  I mean, what's the problem caused by having them in your schema?

Answer (score 3):

`db/schema.rb` is like a *blueprint* of your complete database. So, No, its not possible to have tables in database and avoid showing them in `db/schema.rb` as it will pick the *complete* schema of your database. Even if you go and manually add a new table (i.e., without a migration) in your database, it would still be reflected in `db/schema.rb`

As per the Rails Guide,

> Note that running the db:migrate task also invokes the db:schema:dump
>   task, which will update your db/schema.rb file to **match the structure
>   of your database**.

Another reference from Rails Guide sums it up

> Migrations, mighty as they may be, are not the authoritative source
>   for your database schema. That role falls to either db/schema.rb or an
>   SQL file **which Active Record generates by examining the database**. They
>   are not designed to be edited, **they just represent the current state
>   of the database**.

Answer (score -3):

Create an empty migration file and edit it to use drop table:

`drop_table :table_name`

Comment: Thanks @tTam. Should I still run `rake db:migrate` after?

Comment: This will actually drop the table from database. Is that you want? @jiggabits

Comment: @Kirti No, I don't want to drop the tables from my database.  Just from my schema.